# Unable to append same div

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am having issues while appending same div inside another div. When I click on the add button an empty div is created with no height however I want to append the whole div having all information.

```html
 <div class="column column-3-4" id="customFields">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="column-1-1">
         <div class="user_information" style="margin-top:0px;">
            <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return ugt_validate_profile();">
               <? include('./includes/error-message3.php');
                  $_SESSION['ERROR_MSG3']=NULL;
                  $_SESSION['WARN_MSG3']=NULL;
                  $_SESSION['SUCCESS_MSG3']=NULL;?>    
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div>
                     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder=" Enter The Name:" value="<?=(isset($usr_fname))?$usr_fname:NULL; ?>">
                     <label id="name_error" style="display:none"></label>
                  </div>
                  <div style="float:right">
                     <button><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a></button>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input  type="file" class="form-control" id="formFileId"  name="uplode_img" placeholder=" Upload The Profile Pic" />
                  <label for="input-placeholder" class="control-label"><strong>Best Resolution :( 320 X 320 ),&nbsp;Size: 1024Kb</strong></label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id:" value="<?=(isset($usr_email))?$usr_email:NULL; ?>">
                  <label id="email_error" style="display:none"></label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone No:" value="<?=(isset($usr_mob))?$usr_mob:NULL; ?>" disabled="disabled" readonly>
                  <label id="phone_error" style="display:none"></label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address :" value="<?=(isset($usr_address))?$usr_address:NULL; ?>">
                  <label id="phone_error" style="display:none"></label>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="more" type="submit" name="profile_submit" value="profile_submit" >Save</button>  
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code for appending the div. If I append a textbox then it is working fine. Also remove link is not working correctly. If I click on the remove link it goes to the bottom of the page. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<div id="customFields"></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>');
  });

  $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: You append a new div with used id. It may create confict.

Comment: If i append a div with new id then also i am facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is only for your information , because you can append this div on body, now i just copied your data and add something

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<div id="customFields"></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>');
  });

  $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="customFields"></div>
<a href="#" class="addCF">click me</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".addCF").click(function() {
        $("#customFields").append('<div id="rem_butt"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></div>');
      });

      $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
        $('#formFileId').val('');
        $('#rem_butt').empty();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoy are trying to create two elements with the same id.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

Answer (score 0):

```js
  

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<div id="customFields"></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>');
  });
  $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
     $(this).remove();//OR
     //$(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="customFields"></div>
<a href="#" class="addCF">click me</a>
```

Comment: Now remove is working fine but still i am not able to append div with all the information.I want to append div with #customfields id with all information.thank you for your help.

Comment: could i get the solution please @Soni Vimal

Comment: it my pleasure, for you remain issues ,I can resolve that issues but for that i need to access your code.

Comment: if you can avoid to use same Id than it will good practice to avoid major errors and time as well.

Comment: I do not have 20 reputation that is why i am unable to chat with you. Give me alternate option.@Soni Vimal

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate `id` scenario which is not good. Also you are deleting invalid `parent`. You newly created `div` is also not enclosing the `a` so `remove` will remove the `customFields` div which will breakdown your flow.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.addCF',function() {
    $("#customFields").append('<div id="removeContainer"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></div>');
  });

  $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="customFields"></div>
<a href="#" class="addCF">click me</a>
```